# Error calling the kernel: error code is: -6 on openCL kernel

Tags: c++, opencl, fpga

my question is little different than that being asked on this platform, but I think it is related to programming.
I am using vitis and alveo accelerators. They basically have a host program( written in C++) and than a openCL file, which is also kind of C programming.
The host asks the kernel to do some thing by putting the input data through arguments and than results are send back to the host.
There are 3 ways to execute the data on kernel( Software emulation, HW emulation and Hardware). Generally, we start with Software emulation and than with Hardware. I have always seen that when code gets build and run with software emulation, it also builds and run on Hardware.
But I am getting a strange error as below:

```
INFO: Reading /home/m992c693/Workspace C2Q TC _paper/qht_3d_system/Hardware/vector addition.xclbin
Loading: '/home/m992c693/Workspace C20 TC_paper/qht_3d_system/Hardware/vector_addition.xclbin
Trying to program device[6]: xilinx_u250_gen3x16_xdma_shell_4 |

Device[6]: program successful
-./src/host.cpp:585 Error calling krnt_c2q =
XRT build version: 2.13.466

Build hash: 5505e402c2calffe45eb6d3a9399b23a0dc8776

Build date: 2022-04-14 17:45:07

Git branch: 2022.1

PID: 243276

UID: 100586768

[Tue Sep 27 17:35:28 2622 GMT!

HOST: alveo

EXE: /home/m992c693/Workspace C20 TC_paper/qht_3d/Hardware/qht_3d
[XRT] ERROR: No such compute unit ‘c2q:c2q 1': Invalid argument

:Kernel (program, “c2q", Serr), error code is: -6
```

It would be great if someone can guide me why I am getting this error and what kind of debugging procedure I should follow.

Comment: Did you try asking on Xilinx forum?

Comment: Thank you @Fra93 for the response. I have posted the question on Xilinx forum https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D54U00005eYrFwSAK/error-calling-the-kernel-error-code-is-6-on-opencl-kernel